In manjaro linux, how to get the math rendering extension to work with inkscape
I have downloaded inkscape through the software manager (GUI) in manjaro.
By default it doesn't seem to render math under the extensions drop down. So I have tried multiple solutions. I have installed texlive and textext through pacman and pamac, closed inkscape and even restarted the computer, but I don't get the option in the drop down still.
What should I do?
